# How to remove choose file tooltip from material ui textfield i

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to show only image name in the textfield when image is choosen, don't want choose file button inside textfiled

```
<TextField variant='outlined' fullWidth    type="file"
                                InputProps={{ startAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                                    <PhotoCamera />
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                                }}
                            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change type of TextField from file to text, when file is selected and show name of file in input field. [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-meadow-9nzc8?file=/src/App.js)

```
const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);

    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      value={file?.name||''}
      type={!file ? "file" : "text"}
      onChange={(e) => {
        if (!file) setFile(e.target.files[0]);
      }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <PhotoCamera />
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
    />
```